# SFTP empty directory listing

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I'm trying to access my ubuntu server using SFTP.

I created a user on the server and gave access to the server using ssh key.
The connection works properly.

Then I configured /etc/ssh/sshd_config to restrict the access to only SFTP

```
# myuser user configuration
Match User myuser
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication no
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/myuser
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

Here is the sftp folder on the server

```
$ ls -la /var/sftp/myuser
total 5592
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser    4096 Mar 19 13:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser myuser    4096 Mar 18 10:39 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myuser myuser 3370257 Mar 18 11:18 file1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myuser myuser 2343334 Mar 18 11:18 file2
```

Here is the command I use to connect

```
sftp -i /path/to/ssh_key myuser@myserver
```

The problem is when I connect to the server I can't find any files in the folder /var/sftp/myuser nor can I create any file.

It seems the SFTP root directory is not the right one but I can't find which one is it.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the output of `ls -ld /var/sftp/myuser`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact sftp commands that you're running and the output that you get. Specifically show how you're looking for the /var/sftp/myuser directory, and what happens when you try.

Comment: Does `/var/log/auth.log` say anything interesting about your attempts to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I thought it was a good security practice to make myuser the owner of the folder but making root the admin solved the problem.

Here is the sftp folder on the server now

```
$ ls -la /var/sftp/myuser
total 5592
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar 19 13:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Mar 18 10:39 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3370257 Mar 18 11:18 file1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2343334 Mar 18 11:18 file2
```

myuser doesn't have write access via sftp but in my case it doesn't matter.

Comment: It is written in the manpage, see `man sshd_config`. It is *chroot*, not a start directory. *chroot* dirs should not be writtable by ordinary users, they could write into chroot's subdirs.